# in coin toss game until heads appears, the expected proportion of head is equal to that of tails

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $X$ be the random variable of the probability that first head appears at $x$th throw. This is geometric random variable and we know $E[X] = 2$. Then the last throw is always heads so we see that the expected proportion of heads and tails are $1/2$.

I wanted to show this in another way. Let $Y_i$ be $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $-1$ with prob $1/2$. Then I want to show that  $E(\sum_{1 \leq i \leq T} Y_i) = 0$ where $T$ is the first time $Y_i = 1$. Since each $E(Y_i) = 0$ so it seems like $E(\sum_{1 \leq i \leq T} Y_i) = 0$... but $T$ is not a constant so I don't think one can do this. Is there a way to make this argument more rigorous? thank you

Comment: Note that $T \bar Y = \sum_{1 \le I \le T} Y_i$, then $E(T \bar Y) = E( E(T \bar Y | T)) = E(T E(\bar Y | T)) = E(T(0)) = 0$

Comment: The [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) produces this result immediately as $T$ is a stopping time and $\sum Y_i$ is a martingale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $Y_i$ be 1 with probability $1/2$ and $−1$ with prob $1/2$. Then I want to show that $E(∑_{1≤i≤T}Y_i)=0$ where $T$ is the first time $Y_i=1$.

Notice that $Y_T=1$ and for all $i<T$ we have $Y_i=-1$, then

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E\!\left(\sum_{i=1}^T Y_i\right) &= \mathsf E\!\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{T-1}(-1)\right)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(2-T)\\[1ex]& =2-\mathsf E(T)\\&=0 && \text{because }\mathsf E(T)=2\text{ when the success rate is }1/2\end{align}$

> but T is not a constant so I don't think one can do this.

Indeed, $T$ is a random variable, *but* its expectation is a constant *and* we know its value.